# Setting the include path with bindgen

Tags: rust, ffi

I'm writing a Rust interface to [a small C library](https://github.com/repaper/gratis), which has headers spread in a few locations. It's not a system library, and is normally used by some executables in the same package; I'm currently including it as a git submodule in my Cargo project.

Building the library seems to be pretty easy; I've opted to use the `gcc` crate from `build.rs`:

```
gcc::Config::new()
            .file("external/foo/dir1/file1.c")
            .file("external/foo/dir2/file2.c")
            .include("external/foo/dir1/")
            .include("external/foo/dir2/")
            .include("external/foo/config_a/")
            .compile("libfoo.a");
```

Now I was hoping to use the [`bindgen`](https://docs.rs/bindgen/0.22.1/bindgen/index.html) crate to generate the FFI interface without too much fuss, but it doesn't seem to have a way of setting include paths.

I can create a `wrapper.h` as suggested by [this blog](http://fitzgeraldnick.com/2016/12/14/using-libbindgen-in-build-rs.html) and include several headers, but if `dir1/dir1.h` includes `conf.h` directly, which works when building due to `.include("external/foo/config_a/")` it can't be found.

I can't find anything in `bindgen`'s API to help here (essentially I want to pass the equivalent of gcc/clang's `-I` option).  Am I missing anything?

The best option I can think of so far is to copy the various headers from the library source into some temporary directory in `build.rs` and run `bindgen` on that, but that seems somewhat messy if there's a nicer way.

Answer (score 42):

With the API you can use [`Builder::clang_arg`](https://docs.rs/bindgen/0.22.1/bindgen/struct.Builder.html#method.clang_arg) with arbitrary arguments:

```
let b = bindgen::builder().header("foo.h").clang_arg("-I/path");
```

From the command line you can do the same by appending arguments after `--`, like:

```
bindgen foo.h -- -I/path
```