# Rust Bindgen: Setting include path on windows

Tags: windows, rust, include, rust-bindgen

I'm new to Rust development under Windows.

I'm trying to bindgen a library, `libk4a`, on both windows and linux.On linux it is installed as `libk4a`, under the usual places, `/usr/local/include/k4a/k4a.h` and `/usr/local/lib/libk4a.so`.

I've followed the bindgen book's example and have made a `wrapper.h` to pass to `build.rs`, which is simply:

```
#include <k4a/k4a.h>
```

This works fine under linux with the `build.rs` setting of

```
println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=k4a");
```

On windows, the dll is under `C:\Program Files\Azure Kinect SDK v1.3.0\sdk\windows-desktop\amd64\release\bin\` and the header at `C:\Program Files\Azure Kinect SDK v1.3.0\sdk\include\k4a\k4a.h`

While I'm able to run bindgen on its own with

```
bindgen wrapper.h -- -I "C:\Program Files\Azure Kinect SDK v1.3.0\sdk\include"
```

If it try to add the include path in my build.rs as [this previous answer suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42741815/setting-the-include-path-with-bindgen):

```
   let bindings = bindgen::Builder::default()
        .header("wrapper.h")
        .clang_arg("-I \"C:\\Program Files\\Azure Kinect SDK v1.3.0\\sdk\\include\"")
        .parse_callbacks(Box::new(bindgen::CargoCallbacks))
        .generate()
        .expect("Unable to generate bindings");
```

I still get the error saying it cannot find the header file:

```
wrapper.h:1:10: fatal error: 'k4a/k4a.h' file not found
wrapper.h:1:10: fatal error: 'k4a/k4a.h' file not found, err: true
thread 'main' panicked at 'Unable to generate bindings: ()', build.rs:11:20
```

Am I missing a place to add something to the include path? Should `k4a/k4a.h` be on my path somewhere? Or do I have a typo in my config? I'm not sure why it works with raw `bindgen` on the command line, but not `build.rs`.

Answer (score 1):

This question had a simple answer.

I added the extra clang argument

```
.clang_arg("-v")
```

to see the include path that clang was getting, and I noticed that it showed

```
" C:\Program Files\Azure Kinect SDK v1.3.0\sdk\include\"
```

Basically there was a space before the include path. Removing it made it work.